# Does Java allocate memory to object variables which are not given values?

Tags: java, class, object, memory

I am a beginner in Java, so I don't know about the heap concept when I googled. In an OOP tutorial, I learnt that when we create an object using 'new' keyword, memory is allocated to the object. What if I don't provide values to the attributes of the instance of the class, so will that instance variables also take up memory but they are without any values.

```java
class Employee{
    int age;
    String name;
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee emp = new Employee();
        // I didn't provide any values to age and name
    }
}
```

Comment: "*... OOPs...*" - the right abbreviation is OOP. --- The two types in `Employee` are different in nature. `int age` is a primitive, so even without an intialization, it will hold the value `0` (alll primitives do). For `String name`, memory for a reference is created (since all objects addressed by references). The reference itself will reference `null` since we did not explicitly assign a value to it, signaling that there is currently no reference stored.

Comment: It is important to realise that the space of the variable itself and the space for the value of the variable (for a reference type) are two separate things.

Answer (score -1):

Yes these get default values.
For all primitives (int float etc.) that is 0 or false for booleans.
For objects like strings it is null. It takes the same space as when initializing with null for objects. So it has the 4/8 bytes (32/64 bit) but no object is created yet for the String.

Comment: can you little bit clarify on your last line ?

Comment: The null consumes the reference size, so probably 64 bits or 8 bytes. However no object is allocated

Answer (score -1):

Yes.Once you create an Object using the 'new' keyword , relevant heap space will be allocated because of there are default values for each variable.